# How can I find the DocsList Sheet ID with the sheet URL

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to be able to take a spreadsheet URL value from a cell in the active sheet and be able to add that file to a specific folder. The only thing I think that I am missing is a method to add a file to a folder by URL or to extract the DocsList sheet ID using the URL.

Here is a sample of the code I am using:

```
var rowNum = 1
var colLet = A
var findFolder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName);
var ssURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(colLet+rowNum).getValue();
var ssFileFindID = ?
ssFileFindID.addToFolder( findFolder );
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use string manipulation functions to get the id of the spreadsheet from the URL
e.g
Suppose a spreadsheet url is like the example given below

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&pli=1#gid=1

var ssURL = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(colLet+rowNum).getValue();
var ssFileFindID = ssURL.split('key=')[1].split('&')[0]; //this is ID of file
```

Hope the above hint will help you

Comment: I don't think that the URL key is the same as the DocsList sheet ID. I ran a print screen after capturing the sheet ID of a newly created sheet and the key in the URL was not the same as the ID used in the DocsList function.

Comment: Yes, I know. But both the keys will work. This has already been discussed somewhere but I don't have the link. You may Google it. Key from URL and getting the key programatically using apis come out to be different.